# Referring to a complete subequation environment. Is there a recommended style?

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, amsmath, subequations, alignat

I have a subequations environment which is labelled and inside it I have an alignat environment which has a label for each line.

Would you say it is ok to refer to the complete model as I do it in the MWE, because the concrete label (0.1) cannot be found directly as equation number? Or is there a better way to refer to the complete model, except referring to the range of equations like `(0.1a)--(0.1b)`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
I'm referring to the complete model \eqref{eq:MainLabel} and here to the restrictions \eqref{eq:Sub1} and \eqref{eq:Sub2}
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:MainLabel}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    \sum_{m \in M}  x_m     & = 1      & \quad & , \forall m \in M \colon a \neq b  \label{eq:Sub1} \\
                          x_m     & = 1      && , \forall m \in M \colon e \neq f \label{eq:Sub2}           
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there's a brief "recommendation" in the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsmath`) in section 3.11.3.  actually, it's more a description of what happens with the example shown.  there's a slightly longer example in the ["short math guide"](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) on page 3.

Comment: Is this a question about how to set up TeX and friends in order to cross-reference such a group of equations, or is it about mathematical terminology, i.e., about what to call such a group of equations?

Comment: @Mico Such a group of equations I usually call mathematical program. My question is about how to cross-reference the complete program in (La)TeX. The problem is if you reference the main label  (`eq:MainLabel`) you get an equation number which is not printed within the document directly. So maybe just give the program a name like `DLSP` and refer to it with the name. But I would prefer a solution with an equation number which is also printed near the program.